# Android Gallery change single image on slide

Tags: android, scroll, imageview, gallery

I have used a gallery view which takes the whole space of screen. Normally when user slides left or right, depending upon the user scrolling force, images are moved right and left. I want that when user slides left or right, only a single image moves at a time even if user slides it hardly. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom gallery that extends gallery class, and then you override onfling method. You can refer the code below :
package hung.view;
public class CustomGallery extends Gallery {

```
public CustomGallery(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CustomGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CustomGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    //return false ;
    int kEvent;
      if(isScrollingLeft(e1, e2)){ //Check if scrolling left
        kEvent = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT;
      }
      else{ //Otherwise scrolling right
        kEvent = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT;
      }
      onKeyDown(kEvent, null);
      return true;
}

 private boolean isScrollingLeft(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2){
     return e2.getX() > e1.getX();
  }
```

}

The last, in the layout xml file, you replace default gallery by custom gallery, example :

```
    <hung.view.CustomGallery android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:spacing="8px"
        android:clipToPadding="true"/>
```

I hope it is useful for you.
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own eventListener for scrolling event where you can change the image.